# On building a head tracker for your head mounted display using your android mobile phone

Tags: android, accelerometer, gravity

My goal is to code a headtracker for my head mounted display using my android phone. The movement is transferred to mouse movement, which in turn is used inside pc games. I want to mount my android phone to the back of the head-tracker, so it will be fixed to the back of my head. The y-axis is facing upwards, the x-axis is facing to the right when looking straight ahead, that means when you look at my back head, you see the mobile phone display.

[image: mobile phone image]

Due to mechanics of this setup there is an angle between the y-axis and the gravity-axis, so the mobile phone is tilted slightly away from the back of the head when looking straight forward. Also it is slightly rotated around the z-axis and might be rotating while moving around the z-axis within an angle of about 5 to 10°.

My phone does not have a gyroscope. I used

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
  // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
  // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
  // and dT, the event delivery rate

  final float alpha = 0.8;

  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```

which works better than just using raw data from the accelerometer. I just used 0.8 as alpha, do I need to adjust it according to t / (t + dT)? So how to get t and dT then?

Using this setup, tilting the head up and down works - with some refinement here and there - well.

But moving left and right turns out to be an issue. Also moving diagonal from left-down to right-up and mirrored. Or moving in circles.

Coming from the basic mathematics and not my error description, which code do you suggest to make this work?

Comment: I made the effort of phrasing it well for everyone to understand and learn from it. Give something back.